# Customize the text in a popup menu item programmatically

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I have newly implemented popup menus in my Android project, but I would like to programmatically change the text for one of the menu items, depending on software state.  Is this possible with a pop up menu item??  I can already do it with my Action Bar items using menu.findItem(), but that function doesn't seem to be provided for popupmenu.

This is my code for displaying the menu:

```
private void showPopupMenu (final View v)
{
    PopupMenu pm = new PopupMenu (net, v);
    pm.getMenuInflater().inflate (R.menu.popupmenu, pm.getMenu());

    pm.setOnMenuItemClickListener (new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
    {
            ...
```

I suppose I could create a big set of popupmenu XML's and parse the one I need in inflate(), but really doesn't seem like an efficient way to do it.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: Sort of, but not one that makes me very happy.  Thanks for the reminder. though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, what I decided to do was this:

```
    pm.getMenuInflater().inflate (bConfigSelf
        ?   R.menu.SelfConfigMenu   //  Need a different menu for myself
        :   R.menu.ConfigMenu,      //   than for a neighbor
                pm.getMenu());
```

A choice of 2 different menus didn't seem too outlandish, but this isn't really a solution for the general case.  But I'm going to assume (based on the number of responses) that this isn't a common problem, and that there really isn't a solution to it at this point.